# Unable to add to cart on other .php pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, e-commerce

I'm trying to create a simple ecommerce website. Everything is going well but I can only add products on my cart when I'm in `index.php`. When I try to click the `add_cart` button on `all_products.php` page, it redirects me to the `index.php` page and doesn't add the product to the cart.

I wanted to be able to add products as well on `all_products.php` page. What is wrong with my code:

`function.php`( functions where the "add to cart" button is created and the function on what will happen when the add to cart button is clicked:

```
function getProd(){
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
    global $con;
    $get_prod = "select * from item order by RAND() LIMIT 0, 6";
    $run_prod = mysqli_query($con, $get_prod);
    while($row_prod = mysqli_fetch_array($run_prod)){
        $prod_id = $row_prod['ItemId'];
        $prod_name = $row_prod['ItemName'];
        $prod_desc = $row_prod['ItemDesc'];
        $prod_price = $row_prod['ItemPrice'];
        $prod_qty = $row_prod['ItemQty'];
        $prod_cat = $row_prod['ItemCat'];
        $prod_img = $row_prod['ItemImg'];

        echo "
            <div id='single_product'>

                <img src='../admin_int/product_images/$prod_img' width='180' height=180'/>
                <h4>Name:</h4><h4> $prod_name</h4>
                <p><b>Price: $ $prod_price</b></p>

                <a href='details.php?prod_id=$prod_id' style='float:left; font-size:19px;padding-top:10px;text-decoration:none'>Details</a>

                <a href='index.php?add_cart=$prod_id'><button style = 'float:right; border:1; border-radius:12px; color:blue;
                 height:50px; width:50px;
                 background-color: #80ff80'>
                Add to Cart</button></a> //THIS IS THE CREATION OF ADD TO CART BUTTON
            </div>
        ";
    }

}// if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){

}//END OF getProd()
```

`cart()` // This is what will the `add to cart` button is going to perform.

```
function cart(){

if(isset($_GET['add_cart']))
{   
    global $con;
    $ip = getIp();
    $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];

    $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add = '$ip' AND p_id = '$prod_id" ;

    $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){
            echo "";
        }
        else {
            $insert_pro = "insert into cart (orderId,ip_add) values ('$pro_id','$ip')";
            $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pro);

            echo "<script> window.open('all_products.php','_self')</script>";

        }
}
}//cart()
```

`all_products.php`

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
include("../functions/function.php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Online Shop</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/style.css' media="all"/>
    </head>
<body>  
            <!--Main Wrapper starts here!-->
    <div class="main_wrapper"> 

            <!--Header Wrapper starts here!-->
        <div class="header_wrapper" >
        <a href='index.php'><img id="logo" src="../Pictures/logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
            <!--Header ends here!-->

            <!--Menu Bar starts here!-->
        <div class="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php"> Home </a></li> 
            <li><a href="all_products.php"> All Products </a></li>
            <li><a href="customer/my_account.php"> My Account </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Sign Up </a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.php"> Shopping Cart </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us  </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="user_query"  placeholder="Search Product"/>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" style='background-color:#80dfff; border:none;'/>
            </form> 
        </div>
        </div><!--Menubar ends here!-->

            <!--Content Wrapper here!-->
        <div class="content_wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar"> 
                <div id="sidebar_title"> Categories</div>
                <ul id="cats">

                    <?php getCats(); ?>     

                </ul>   
            </div>
            <!--CONTENT AREA starts here-->
            <div id="content_area">
                <?php cart(); ?>
                <div id='shopping_cart'>
                    <span style='float:right; font-size:18px; padding-right:5px; padding:5px; line-height:40px;'>
                     Welcome Guest!
                      <b style='color:#336600'>SHOPPING CART</b>
                      Total Items:<?php total_items(); ?>
                       Total Price: <?php total_price(); ?>
                     <a href="cart.php" style='color:#336600'>Go to Cart</a>

                    </span>

                </div>

                <div id="product_box">
                <!--CODE IN SHOWING ALL PRODUCTS-->
                <?php   
                    $get_prod = "select * from item order by ItemName";
                    $run_prod = mysqli_query($con, $get_prod);
                    while($row_prod = mysqli_fetch_array($run_prod)){
                        $prod_id = $row_prod['ItemId'];
                        $prod_name = $row_prod['ItemName'];
                        $prod_desc = $row_prod['ItemDesc'];
                        $prod_price = $row_prod['ItemPrice'];
                        $prod_qty = $row_prod['ItemQty'];
                        $prod_cat = $row_prod['ItemCat'];
                        $prod_img = $row_prod['ItemImg'];
                    echo "
                    <div id='single_product'>
                    <img src='../admin_int/product_images/$prod_img' width='180' height=180'/>
                    <h4>Name:</h4><h4> $prod_name</h4>
                    <p><b>Price: $ $prod_price</b></p>

                    <a href='details.php?prod_id=$prod_id' style='float:left; font-size:19px;padding-top:10px;text-decoration:none'>Details</a>

                    <a href='index.php?prod_id=$prod_id'><button style = 'float:right; border:1; border-radius:12px; color:blue;
                     height:50px; width:50px;
                     background-color: #80ff80'>
                    Add to Cart</button></a>
                    </div>
                    ";
                    }
                    ?> <!--END OF ALL PRODUCTS-->

                </div>

            </div><!--END OF CONTENT AREA-->
        </div><!--Content Wrapper ends here!-->
        <div id="footer"><h2 style='text-align:center; padding-top:25px;'>&copy; Jerlon Buenconsejo 2015</h2> </div>
    </div><!--Wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirected to index.php because this is the page specified in your link :

```
<a href='index.php?prod_id=$prod_id'>
```

Change it for the name of your page. Also, you will need the cart() function to be called on top of your page.

You should consider to call a unique page which is addCaddy.php for an example, that redirect to the page where you were after inserting the product, or that you could call with ajax.